# Mercedes Benz E300 BlueTEC HYBRID

Tags: bmw, mercedes-benz

Could anyone please tell me what `BlueTEC HYBRID` and `Blue Efficiency` mean and the pros and cons of those ? Are those better than BMWs `Efficient Dynamics` ? Common faults they undergo ? Maintenance criteria ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you finally got a hit on a potentially technical question   :-)

Comment: @DucatiKiller hahahah !! yeah yeah !!! (Y)

Comment: This question seems very broad.  You seem to have three distinct questions that could stand on their own with a little more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BlueEFFICIENCY**

As Mercedes-Benz claims, it reduces fuel consumption by up to [12.1%](http://forums.mercedesclub.org.uk/attachment.php?attachmentid=12551&d=1282863145), without a performance drop. They also claim that it is environment-friendly (Consume less fuel and emit less CO2) They are achieving these by doing:

- Reducing car's weight
- Lower aerodynamic drag
- Smart dynamo
- Fraction resisted tyres
- Transmission suggestion monitor
- Fuel-save gear ratio
- Engine start-stop rest state in traffic

**BlueTEC**

A better and newer version of BlueEFFICIENCY again by MB.

you can see comparison of [2011](http://forums.mercedesclub.org.uk/attachment.php?attachmentid=12551&d=1282863145):

```
S350 CDI BlueEFF   vs   S350 BlueTEC
     2987cc        -       2987cc
     235hp       +8.50%    255hp
     540Nm       +7.00%    580Nm
     37.2 mpg    +13.0%    42.2 mpg
     199 g/km    -11.0%    178 g/km
```

so you can see the power & performance increase, fuel economy and reduced CO2.

**EfficientDynamics**

BMW version of Mercedes-Benz BlueTEC.

I won't be listing additionally because they are nearly the same but [here](http://s1.cdn.autoevolution.com/images/news/an-in-depth-look-at-how-bmw-s-efficientdynamics-works-70177_7.png) is a picture which shows the ED specs

**Summary**

Increased performance, better fuel economy and less CO2.

I was a BMW E46 3.20i user, and now I have got a BMW F30 3.20i

Thinking about it and there is too much improvement in technical specs between 2 cars. I believe it will continue to improve drastically with the developing technology.

I am very happy with my car so the difference is real :) As for MB, I am not a fan of it, but I am sure (and most people say) BMW and MB are similar and in competition with each other so you can expect the same outcome.